# Change case of argument provided to C preprocessor macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm fairly new to the C preprocessor. Is it possible to change the case of an argument provided to a function-like `#define`? For example, I want to write `test(size)` and then involve "Size" in the resulting replacement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  The preprocessor can combine identifiers to form new ones, but it cannot modify an identifier.

Comment: So, to do this--I probably won't now :(--I'd need to use something more like `test(s,S,ize)` (eww)?

Comment: @andyvn:  You could do it that way; note that the first parameter is unneeded.  There's not much point in doing that, of course, since you have to give it the capital letter ;-).

Comment: @andyvn22 - or you can do something like `test(size, Size)` - it's more redundant but has less of an eww fact (at least to me).

Comment: `test(size,Size)` it is. I'm not happy about it, though. :P