# How to convert identifier letter case in c++ macros

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change case of argument provided to C preprocessor macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777721/change-case-of-argument-provided-to-c-preprocessor-macro)

I have the following cpp code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define PROPERTY(name,type) type get ## name () { return name; } void set ## name ( type value ) { this-> name ; }

class Demo {

  string name;

public:
  PROPERTY(name,string)

  Demo() {
      name = "no name";
  }
};

int main(){
  Demo demo;
  cout << demo.getname();
  return 0;
}
```

according to the code above, the macro will generate a method named "getname" , i want to make it "getName"

how to do change tokens case in macros ?

Comment: I don't think you can. Which should not be a problem, because that macro adds about nothing over `public: string name;`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes I was gonna say it adds the ability to debug... but then I changed my mind. :)

Comment: ok, i will add a new parameter that specify the name of the method, i.e PROPERTY(name,string,Name)

Answer (score 1):

Capitalize 'name', i.e.

```
string Name;
```

That will generate **getName**() and **setName**(string)

It's probably not what you're looking for, but it will have the same effect. I don't think there are any preprocessor tricks that will capitalize tokens.

Another alternative style is to use get_name() and set_name(string)

Comment: What C++ compiler are you using that automatically generates those member functions?

Comment: ok i was thinking about that, but it's a private member.

Comment: I used gcc (g++) to test it, but it should work with any compiler.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious there's a macro defined in the question's source.